# Modifying tilestache.cfg file does reflect in the api calls (Suspected cache issues)

Tags: mapnik, tilemill, tilestache

i have setup my tilestache server and serving my tilemill xml files.
I have followed this tutorial for serving own tilemill files.
https://go.yuri.at/running-a-map-server-with-mapnik-and-tilestache-on-ubuntu-16-04/

There are problems which i am facing after installing tilestache on ubuntu 16.04.

**Any changes in the tilestache.cfg file does not reflect when doing a HTTP GET call. For example, if i alter the mapnik file name in tilestache.cfg to some random file location like ("provider": {"name": "mapnik", "mapfile": "/home/Documts/sample.xml"},), the server still gives me the old cached png while accessing localhost:8080/layername/0/0/0.png.**

Any help would be appreciated!!
Thanks.